# What is the purpose of pthread and the select () function?

Tags: c, linux, unix, select, pthreads

Our professor gave us this code in class:

```
st = select(max+1, &rs, NULL, NULL, &timeinterval);

 if(st){ 
        for(int i=0; i<workers; i++)
        {

            if(FD_ISSET(channels[i]->read_fd(), &rs))
```

and I honestly have a hard time trying to understand what it's doing. I've tried to research more about pthreads but nothing seems to show up to explain what this is doing. He says it has something to do with file descriptors but I don't get how this is being in this code.

Comment: `select` is not inherently associated with pthreads. So without more context it is not clear what your prof is referring to and thus not clear what you are asking. If you want to know just what `select` does then the place to start is the [select man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select).

Comment: He's teaching us to use a single event handler thread to manage all the channels for data communication with the server. Instead of using worker threads to handle with one on one requests, he wants us to learn about event handlers and reduce thread management overhead. Also thank you for the link! I just need help understanding what this code is exactly doing

Comment: And how about the man page? Did reading that help? If not, which part did you not understand? In summary, `select` allows you to watch multiple file descriptors for defined events. When any of those events occurs (e.g. input available on one of the fds) then the select will unblock and the fd set can be examined to see which fd has an event.

Comment: I understand what the select function does, but what does a file descriptor have to do with handling data requests to the server and back? I guess that should have been my first question.

Comment: @Teflondre So your question is "what is a file descriptor"?

Comment: @immibis, i guess now that me and kaylum were talking out things, yes, what is a file descriptor? in which this case you don't have to answer. i'll look for it :)

Comment: Well, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) tells us that an fd is: "an abstract indicator (handle) used to access a file or other input/output resource". In your case the I/O resource is a data channel to/from the server. So by monitoring an fd you can know when data is available from a particular server.

Comment: A file descriptor is the Linux equivalent of a channel/socket/`FILE*`/etc. Linux only knows about file descriptors - if you have some kind of channel object, then it must contain a file descriptor somewhere, and when you read from it, it somehow eventually asks Linux to read from that file descriptor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of this `select` is to wait on multiple file descriptors, with a possibly time out, when it returns with a positive number, that means at least one fd in the `rs` set becomes ready for reading, so that in a loop, you check which fd is it, and performs read on it.

Note, you should check for bigger than 0 instead, because -1 will be returned in case of error, which you should not check the fd_set but handle the error:

```
if(st > 0) { 
    for(int i=0; i<workers; i++)
    {
        if(FD_ISSET(channels[i]->read_fd(), &rs)) {
             // perform read on channels[i]->read_fd
        }
    }
} else if (st == 0) {
    // handle time out
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the select function to create a delay for short timer. I wonder if usleep(x) or sleep(x) is better than this one, although this might be more precise:

```
void delay(double time)
{
    if ( time<0.000001)
    {
        return;
    }
    int uSec =static_cast<int>(time*1000.0f);
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_usec =(__suseconds_t)uSec;
    tv.tv_sec = (time_t)(uSec / 1000000);

    select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
}
```